# Create date array from two dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array like,

```
 $my_array=array(array('month'=> 3,
                       'day'=> 4,
                       'hour' => 1,
                       'minut' => 15,
                       'year'=> 2014),
                    array('month'=> 5,
                       'day'=> 7,
                       'hour' => 1,
                       'minut' => 50,
                       'year'=> 2012)
                       ----------
                        );
```

I want to create a new array from this array like,

```
$new_array=array('2014-3-4 1:15','2012-5-7 1:50');
```

I know it is possible with traversing each element with a loop,Is there any easy way?.because my array contain large number(**more than 50000**) of data.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this using [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map):

```
$newArr = array_map(function($d) {
    return $d['year'] . '-' . $d['month'] . '-' . $d['day'] . ' ' . $d['hour'] . ':' . $d['minut'];
}, $my_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ofc its possible:

```
foreach($my_array as $k => $v) {
    $new_array[i] = $v["year"]."-".$v["month"]."-".$v["day"]." ".$v["hour"].$v["minut"];
    i++;
}
```

//Untested

Comment: I know this method.But my array is too large.it will timeout before foreach

Comment: http://de1.php.net/set_time_limit should do it. Dont forget to give the user feedback that the script is still working.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map), but, please, note: this will **use loop** internally.

```
$result = array_map(function($x)
{
   return $x['year'].'-'
         .$x['month'].'-'
         .$x['day'].' '
         .$x['hour'].':'
         .$x['minut'];
}, $my_array);
```

So, this won't increase overall performance. Also it won't check your dates. I recommend to use [`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime) and [`date()`](http://php.net/date) so you'll be able to result in any date format. Or may be use [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/checkdate) if you'll need to check if element contains valid date (btw, good alternative to those functions is [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) API)

The only good thing about plain concatenation is that is will be a little bit faster (because in case of using date functions there will be overhead, obviously).